# Reduce the size of VMware disk

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I am running Ubuntu 14 LTS as a virtual machine with VMware player 6.07. The machine is currently using 24.7 GB but the maximum size available to the disk is 230 GB. The disk space is not preallocated, however, my host operating system (windows 7) sees this maximum 230 GB file for the VMWare guest OS and thinks my disk is full. I can't find any good instructions for how to reduce the file size. I have run

```
sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /
```

within the Ubuntu Guest operating system, however, I don't know how to reduce the maximum size allocated to the guest OS. This command merely shrinks the used space (in my case from 32GB to 24.7 GB), but doesn't change how windows sees the guest os.

Comment: Fill unused space with zeros first: 

 `cat /dev/zero > zero.fill;sync;sleep 1;sync;rm -f zero.fill`
and then shrink image with vmware-tools:
 `sudo vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /`

Answer (score -1):

It sounds as if you have no extra disk space.  You would be able to do this using the VMware converter program, recreating the virtual machine in a different place:

- [Growing, thinning, and shrinking virtual disks for VMware ESX and ESXi (1002019)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1002019)

> Shrinking of a thin disk can be performed only by using VMware Converter in the virtual machine and performing a virtual to virtual migration.

- [Decrease Disk Volume Size](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/459088?tstart=0)

Answer (score -3):

I did the following.

install the vmware tools

`sudo apt install open-vm-tools`

then tell vmware to shrink the virtual disk to match actual space used.

`vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /`

Comment: OP said he already did that. You might want to re-read the question.